# What is the exact difference between get_list_or_404 and get_object_or_404 in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am slightly confused by the difference between get_list_or_404 and get_object_or_404 in Django. I am using the object one on getting posts of a particular user but would like to know more on how I could be using get_list_or_404.

Comment: Heads up: get_list_or_404 is an underused API for good reason: it turns what already is an ordered sequence into a writeable ordered sequence that can no longer be queried. There are very few use cases where this is needed. If your next step is to loop through the list and render output or pass to a template, then you **don't** need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

is shortcut for

try:
    return Model.objects.get(pk=...)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404()
```

```
def get_list_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
Returns the result of filter() on a given model manager cast to a list, raising Http404 if the resulting list is empty.

is shortcut for

obj_list = list(Model.objects.filter(title=...))
if not obj_list:
    raise Http404()
return obj_list
```

As get_object_or_404 shortcut call get(), a MultipleObjectsReturned exception will be raised if more than one object is found.

As get_list_or_404 shortcut returns a list, no such exception will be raised except returned list is not empty.